# What does initiative do?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I am playing Knights of Pen and Paper, but i do not know what initiative does and how it affects battles. What is initiative and what does it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initiative determines fight order. The higher the initiative, the earlier that character gets to act. There might be a random component as well, to provide some variation.

Comment: There *is* a random component for the record.  What it is I am not sure, but I've seen my highest initiative people go last, the order is not the same every time etc.